# Using CFContent on IE with SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

CFContent does not work with IE on a SSL site. I have been looking for a fix but have not found one. As an alternative I was to have the CFContent download the excel sheet to a directory and then use cflocation to forward to that file. I really have no use for all of these files on my hard drive though.

I even tried using CFHeader

```
<CFHEADER NAME="Content-Disposition" VALUE="inline; filename=emp.xls"> 
<CFCONTENT TYPE="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You specifically say that it does not work with IE. Does it work with other browsers (albeit outside of the browser)?  Does it work without SSL? Typically with issues like these over SSL it has to do with caching and/or the IE setting _do not save encrypted pages to disk_.

Comment: It works perfectly with Firefox or IE without SSL. I believe it has something to do with the IE headers specifically.

Comment: My suggestion would be to install Fiddler and watch the HTTP traffic that's happening when you try to download the file over SSL. That should show you exactly where things are going wrong with your process.

Comment: @DanShort Good suggestion. Fiddler would need to be installed Server side, correct?

Comment: Check to see if your IE settings have _do not save encrypted pages to disk_ enabled (checked). Under Internet Options > Advanced > under the Security section. If it is checked, try with it disabled (unchecked).

Comment: @Miguel-F It is unchecked.

Comment: Are you sending any no-cache headers? Fiddler will show you this and you should be able to use it on your IE machine, not the ColdFusion server.  [See this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431).

Comment: Fiddler is installed in the browser that's doing the request. If you want something on the server (which I don't think you'll need for this testing) then you'd need to look at something like Wireshark.

Comment: Thank you @Miguel-F!! I deleted the no-cache headers in IIS and that did the trick. If you would answer the question I'll vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically issues like this with Internet Explorer and SSL have to do with caching.

Make sure that Internet Explorer does not have the setting *Do not save encrypted pages to disk* enabled (checked). You can find that setting in IE under Internet Options > Advanced > under the Security section.

Make sure that you are not sending `no-cache` headers with the response. Like these for example:

```
<cfheader name="PRAGMA" value="NO-CACHE" />
<cfheader name="CACHE-CONTROL" value="NO-CACHE" />
```

*Note that some hardware/web servers can also send these no-cache headers if configured to do so.*
You can use a network monitoring tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to "see" these headers.

Comment: I also wanted to add that in IIS 6 it adds no-cache under the specific website. By going to the properties of the website and click on the HTTP Headers tab.. Simply delete no-cache under "Custom HTTP Headers"

Comment: @CoryFail that's what I was trying to show with my note at the bottom. By the way, I don't think that is there by default in IIS. I hope that removing the header does not adversely affect your site. Will IIS allow you to remove the header at the folder and/or file level?

Comment: Yes it will. Using the same method as mentioned in my previous comment.. Instead of going to the website properties just browse to the folder or file and edit those properties instead. I believe the no-cache is added automatically to SSL sites.